# display * instead of password value in the display table in list page?

Tags: javascript, html

i have a table with the fields username , password , email and phone . but the display page should show the value off the password as *****  . only when editing it should show the value ! 
Eg: take my password as pass1234
it should be displayed in list page as *******
but wen editing it it should show as pass1234 . how can i do that ?

Comment: Showing the password in plain text at all violates web conventions as it allows shoulder surfing. Also it implies you are storing it in a non hashed form. The plain text of the password should not be retrievable once saved as many people reuse passwords across sites.

Comment: What do you mean by "table"? A table of all your users' passwords, or a `<table>` with columns for the name, password, email and phone of *one* user?

Comment: <input type="password" > will do this. But as @MartinSmith told you, you should hash the passwords when they are stored in a db :)

Comment: yeah it is a a table with all users data . so in list page the password should not be visible directly instead to store as some *****. While editing it can show the actual password

Answer (score 0):

This requires some Javascript `onfocus` handler:

```
field = document.getElementById('pass');
field.onfocus(function() { this.setAttribute('type','text'); });
field.onblur(function() { this.setAttribute('type', 'password'); });
```

Comment: What's `setAttr`; never heard of that method? Also, you forgot to mention that this does not work in IE

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake. And regarding IE, he can replace it with `this.type = 'text'`.

Answer (score 0):

You should only show the password in plaintext when the user asks for it, e.g. by clicking a button. What do you think the asterisks are good for?

However, you can't just set the `type` of the input, because IE does not allow that. So you will need to completely replace the element. For

```
<input name="pw" id="pw" type="password"></input>
<label><input id="plain" type="checkbox"></input>Show plaintext</label>
```

the JS would look like this (using jQuery for event attaching and co, you should be able to adapt this if you need):

```
$("#plain").change(function() {
     var pw = $("#pw"),
         type = this.checked ? "text" : "password";
     if (type == pw.prop("type")) return;
     $("<input>", {name: "pw", id:"pw", type:type}) // could be done programatically
       .val(pw.val())
       .replaceAll(pw);
});
```

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. As usual, IE comes out to be a pain in the a**!